# How to run the Software Center (it is not in the Unity cog menu)?

Tags: unity, software-center

I can't for the life of me figure out where to find the Software Center... I know you can run it from the terminal but I'd rather do it visually. This is in Ubuntu 12.04.3.

Comment: so you mean you can not find the SC in unity ?

Comment: press the Windows (Super) key and start typing "software centre" -- you'll see it pop up in the list of applications

Answer (score 1):

The Software Center is not in the cog menu on the right side of the top panel.

It may be in the Unity launcher already. That's the vertical bar of icons on the left side of the screen.

If not, click the home button (Ubuntu logo at the top of the launcher) or press <kbd>Super</kbd> (i.e., <kbd>Windows</kbd>), and start typing *software center* in the textbox until the Software Center appears as a search result. Then click on it to run it.

Alternatively, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `software-center` (just as you would do if you were running it from the Terminal). Press enter to run the Software Center.

If it wasn't already in the launcher before you ran it, it should appear in the launcher once you've started it. Then you can **right-click on its icon in the Unity launcher and select the option to *pin* it**. That will keep it easily accessible in the launcher, even after you've exited it, and it will be easy to run in the future.

This general methods works for almost any graphical program (though the technique for typing the command for it is only applicable if you know the command). For example, if Firefox didn't appear in the Unity launcher, you could search for it, run it, and pin it, all the same way.